# How to get full root on a Samsung S-3

Tags: rooting

I have a Samsung S-3 which was updated OTA to Android 4.3. Trying to get root, I downloaded saferoot (source) from xda.

The exploit works, the process gets root permissions (remounting partitions, read/write system directory, and I was able to add setuid bit to a su executable).

From there, I disabled all KNOX related processes. However, the "system" function doesn't work (permission denied) and neither do any "setuid" executables in /system/xbin.

I suspect it's because SELinux.

Did anyone experience these problems, and what did they do to solve them?

Answer (score 0):

VZW OTA, right? Well, as per the XDA page in question, I'm supposed to taunt you for not reading the red large writing, but the page says clearly, *twice*, that 'using this WILL NOT set the "Knox Warranty Void" flag.' It sets the "custom" flag; don't worry about that now. **Later on,**

> Resetting the "Custom" and open padlock indication during boot can be worked around using the **Xposed Framwork and Wanam Xposed**. Get those two from the Play Store. In Wanam, tick "Security Hacks", "Fake System Status".

So you're not unlocking that phone any further than it already is; and you're not installing a custom recovery. You can install [Safestrap recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2605648) (*unless you have encryption enabled; SS will bootloop if encryption is enabled*). SS is a modified TWRP for your rooted-but-unlocked S3; that's the only recovery we OTA Jellybean users have got right now.

Note: you can only use ROMs based on 4.3 *modified for a rooted but locked* SGS3 (there are a few). Any ROM you install with SS is going to sit on top of the stock ROM that we can't (yet) get access to, and *all of that* goes in internal memory, so keep ROM size in mind when shopping ROMs.

Last thing: before Safestrap, if you want wifi, you need to flash [the kernel modules](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/31329-kerneltwml1-v40-11114-leankernel-minimalistic-kernel/). All that info is in the SS thread which *I highly suggest reading*. (I can only post 2 links since I'm new here; I chose carefully, but please read the SS page.)

Comment: no, http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2565758

Comment: Also, try reading the /data/data without root. I did it :)